# How to enable IIS cache in a such a way that browsers won't even check if the resource has changed?

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7, caching

We enabled static resource caching in our ASP.NET application like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Thu, 29 Oct 2020 00:00:00 GMT" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Using a sniffer, we can confirm that the `Expires` tag is actually being placed on the respose's header.

However, the browsers insist on requesting the server to check whether the resource has changed or not. The server returns a not modified code (304). This is, indeed, a very light weight request but we're highly concerned about performance so we'd like to save theses requests.

**How can I tell the brosers they shouldn't even request the server?**

PS: ETags are properly being sent to the client. I thought that if I removed them the browsers could somehow stop requesting the server but I couldn't remove these tags on IIS 7. I don't know if it would help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something's not adding up, what you've described should be sufficient for eliminating the If-Modified-Since/304 behavior. Can you include all response headers, so we can have a closer look?

Also, note that hitting '**Refresh**' would cause what you've described - what you should be testing is an actual **link to the page** in question.

FYI, I posted a similar question a while ago (1), except that I was seeing the opposite: the normal If-None-Match/304 interaction was optimized away by the browser (in the same session).

(1)
[ETags, IIS7, Kernel Cache Policy (enableKernelCache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948727/etags-iis7-kernel-cache-policy-enablekernelcache)

Comment: Thanks Nariman. Before posting response headers, I'll test the 'link to the page' as you described. I'm hitting F5. I don't know how I didn't think of that before, it makes sense. I'll test and come back to you.